# Can Pressflow 7 be a drop-in replacement for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

The Pressflow site mentions that it is used by many ***Drupal 6*** sites, and in the FAQ, in answer to the question "What's the deal with Pressflow 7?" says

> Pressflow 6 made significant improvements to Drupal core in
>   scalability and performance and most of these features have been
>   contributed back to Drupal 7 core. Until well understood performance
>   patches are created for Drupal 7 Pressflow development will be slow.
>   Additionally, as Drupal 8 matures, significant enhancements will
>   likely be backported to Pressflow 7.

That sounds to me like a very indirect way of implying that there are lots of problems with Pressflow 7 that cause people to avoid using it, but stated in a way that no one would understand unless they're already aware of the problems.  The answer seems like more of an explanation (indirect and implied) of *why* there are problems, than really an explanation of *what the situation is* with Pressflow 7.

So, can anyone tell me in plain English what the situation is?  Is there some reason I wouldn't want to replace a normal Drupal 7 site with Pressflow 7?  Or some reason it is simply impossible?  (Or is the problem simply that Pressflow 7 has not been optimized to the same degree that Pressflow 6 has?)

Comment: Have you run a diff to what the difference are?  The last time I did this (granted it was probably around the time Drupal 7.9 was out), the source trees were sufficiently identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that there are problems with Pressflow 7, but that there are no significant benefits to it at this time. This is stated in the lines above your quote:

> If your project is built on Drupal 7 you might not need to use
>   Pressflow at this time because the key enhancements from Pressflow 6
>   were added to Drupal 7.

You could use Pressflow 7 as a replacement, but why bother if there are no advantages? (I haven't actually used Pressflow 7 because of this).

Comment: I wish they would have put that bit *in* the answer to "What's the deal with Pressflow 7?"  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pressflow is a Drupal fork. Pressflow 6's code is different from Drupal 6, and it is more performant. (Pressflow 6 is used on Drupal.org, as far as I know.)
What the quoted text means is that, since some of the code used from Pressflow 6 became part of Drupal 7 (thanks to the patches offered from the team who develops Pressflow), the development of Pressflow 7 is slowing down. Once the development of Drupal 8 is more stable, the code of Drupal 8 will be possibly back-ported to Pressflow 7.

At the actual state, Pressflow 7 is more performant of Drupal 6, but it is similar to Drupal 7.